# Update array of objects based on string search : Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a function that takes string as an input, and based on this input I need to update a result array . Whenever there is string "OR" is present in the input , i need to take rest of the items other than OR and update the result by creating an object for each of the item in the input. When there is "AND" present in the string, I just have to take the whole input as the result.

```
function checkValid(str) {
   let search = null;
   let textContent = str.split(" ");
   const orArr = ["OR", "or", "Or", "oR"];
   if (textContent.includes("OR") || textContent.includes("or")) {
      const removedOR = textContent.filter((item) => orArr.includes(item));
      search = removedOR.map((item) => {
        return { type: "search", value: item};
      });
    } else {
      search = { type: "search", value: str };
    }
    return [...search]
}
```

For the input `1 OR 2`, output should be
`{ type: "search", value: 1 } { type: "search", value: 2 }`

For the input `1 OR 2 AND 3`, output should be
`{ type: "search", value: "1 OR 2 AND 3" }`

For the input `1 OR 23 OR 5`, output should be
`{ type: "search", value: 1 } { type: "search", value: 23 } { type: "search", value: 5 }`

For the input `1 AND 3`, output should be
`{ type: "search", value: "1 AND 3" }`

I am having trouble writing a function for checking if AND is present in the string when there is OR as well. Also let me know if there is any betterment that can be made

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
const checkValid = string => {
  let words = string.toUpperCase().split(' ')
  if (words.includes('AND')) {
    return [{ type: 'search', value: string }]
  }
  
  words = words.filter(word => word !== 'OR')
  
  return words.map(word => ({ 
    type: 'search',
    value: word
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **:**

```js
function checkValid(str) {
  // convert whole input into an upper case so that we can easily compare it without having any seperate OR array.
  let textContent = str.toUpperCase().split(' ');

  // If any 'AND' found in a string this function will return the output.
  if (textContent.includes('AND')) {
    return [{ type: 'search', value: str }]
  }

  // Logic if 'OR' found in the input string
  if (textContent.includes('OR')) {
    textContent = textContent.filter(item => item !== 'OR')
    return textContent.map(item => {
      return {
        type: 'search',
        value: item
      }
    })
  }
}

console.log(checkValid('1 AND 2 OR 3'));
```